# How to refactor "shared" methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, refactoring

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to "extract" some methods from my models / classes. That is, in more than one class / model I have some methods (note: methods are related to *user authorizations* and are named the "[CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) way") that are and work practically the same; so I thought that a [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach is to put those methods in a "shared" module or something like that.

*What is a common and right way to accomplish that?* For example, where (in which directories and files) should I put the "shared" code? how can I include mentioned methods in my classes / models? what do you advice about?

*Note*: I am looking for a "Ruby on Rails Way to make things".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One popular approach is to use ActiveSupport concerns. You would then place the common logic typically under `app/concerns/` or `app/models/concerns/` directory (based on your preference). An illustrative example:

```
# app/concerns/mooable.rb
module Mooable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_create :say_moo

    self.mooables
      where(can_moo: true)
    end
  end

  private

  def say_moo
    puts "Moo!"
  end
end
```

And in the model:

```
# app/models/cow.rb
class Cow < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Mooable
end
```

In order to make it work this way you have to add the following line to `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/concerns)
```

More information:

- http://chris-schmitz.com/extending-activemodel-via-activesupportconcern/
- http://blog.waxman.me/extending-your-models-in-rails-3
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: What about adding the module to the `lib` directory?

Comment: *Note*: The question in the previous comment is due to the addiction of the `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/concerns)`: is that approach a "good way to make things" in my case?

Comment: @user12882 Yes, that can be done in a similar way. `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` or `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/concerns)`

Comment: Sorry if I could "insist" / "repeat myself", but what is the most used approach (`lib` or `app/concerns` directory)?

Comment: @user12882 I believe `app/concerns` originates from here: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/17/concerns-in-activerecord We have used it in our projects. This useful gist mentions `app/models/concerns` and `app/controllers/concerns`- might be good idea you want to DRY controllers, too: http://gist.github.com/1014971 In the end it's all up to you :).

Answer (score 1):

My answer has nothing to do with RoR directly but more with Ruby.

Shraing common code may be done in various ways in Ruby. In my opinion the most obvious way is to create Ruby Modules that contain the code and then include them inside your class/model. Those shared modules are frequently under the lib directory of your app root. For example:

```
# lib/authorizable.rb

module Authorizable
  def method1
     #some logic here
  end

  def method2
     #some more logic here
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Authorizable
 end
```

The User class may now invoke method1 and method2 which belong to the Authorizable module. You can include this module in any other Ruby class you'd like, this way you DRY your code.

Comment: I might point out [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), which is a common utility class used for this purpose in Rails.

Comment: Your code works, but I am looking for a more "Ruby on Railities" way to make things as @numbers1311407 said.

Comment: Then I advice you to mention it in your question. This way you will get answers that are closer to what you are looking for.